# c++ const member function that accepts modification of specified member variable (relaxed const)

Tags: c++, caching, function-qualifier

I have the following class Sample. Say, I wanna perform some heavy computation using member variable `var` and cache the result in case I will do the same computation again. I also guarantee that non-cached variable `var` be const, and if not, I wanna get an error at the compilation time. So, what I want to do is to const-nize `heavy_compuation` in a way that mutation of only `cache` is accepted. Is there any way to do this kind of thing?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
class Sample
{
  public:
    Sample(int var_) : var(var_){}
    std::map<int, int> cache;
    int var;
    int heavy_computation(int x) 
    {
      std::map<int, int>::iterator iter = cache.find(x);
      if(iter == cache.end()){ // cache doesn't exist
        int y = var + x; 
        cache[x] =y;
        return var;
      }
      std::cout << "cached one" << std::endl; 
      return iter->second;
    }
};

int main(){
  Sample s(0);
  s.heavy_computation(1);
  s.heavy_computation(1);
}
```

Comment: You are looking for [`mutable` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#mutable_specifier)

Comment: ahh! that's what I am looking for, thanks!